# proper way to create multiple forked threads

Tags: c, embedded

I'm creating a timer function for a bit of embedded code that will allow me to bypass certain GPIO checks while a certain process is running, i.e., when the timer is running in a non-blocking manner.

This seems to run just fine the first 11 times the operations occur, but every time, on the 11th iteration the system will crash.  The likely culprit is something in how the timer thread is being handled.   My guess is there's some bit of memory cleanup that I'm not handling properly and that's leading to memory leaks of some kind.  But I'm really not sure.

I can see through debug tracing that the thread is exiting after each iteration.

Here is the timer code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <msp432e4_timer.h>

extern void TaskSleep(uint32_t delay);

static bool timerActive;
static sem_t timerSem;

pthread_t timerThread;
pthread_attr_t attrs;
struct sched_param priParam;


static void *msp432e4_timer(void *argUnused) {
    sem_wait(&timerSem);
    timerActive = true;
    sem_post(&timerSem);

    TaskSleep(40);

    sem_wait(&timerSem);
    timerActive = false;
    sem_post(&timerSem);

    return (NULL);
}

void initTimer() {
    int retc;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    priParam.sched_priority = 1;
    retc = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrs, &priParam);
    retc |= pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    retc |= pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 1024);
    if (retc != 0) {
        // failed to set attributes
        while (1) {}
    }

    timerActive = false;
    if((sem_init(&timerSem, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        while(1);
    }
    sem_post(&timerSem);
}

/*
 * return true on starting a new timer
 * false implies timer already active
 */
void timerStart() {
    int retc;
    retc = pthread_create(&timerThread, &attrs, msp432e4_timer, NULL);
    if (retc != 0) {
        // pthread_create() failed
        while (1) {}
    }
}

/* return true if timer active */
bool timerCheck() {
    bool retval;
    sem_wait(&timerSem);
    retval = timerActive;
    sem_post(&timerSem);
    return(retval);
}
```

The TaskSleep function is a call to a freeRTOS TaskDelay function.   It's used in many points throughout the system and has never been an issue.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you didn't really post enough of your code to determine where the problems might be, but I thought this might be worth mentioning:

A general problem is that the sample code you have is open loop wrt thread creation; that is there is nothing to throttle it, and if your implementation has a particularly slow thread exit handling, you could have many zombie threads lying around that haven't died yet.

In typical embedded / real time systems, you want to move resource allocation out of the *main loop*, since it is often non deterministic.  So, more often you would create a timer thread, and *park* it until it is needed:

```
void *TimerThread(void *arg) {
     while (sem_wait(&request) == 0) {
           msp432e4_timer(void *arg);
     }
     return 0
}
void TimerStart(void) {
     sem_post(&request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,   That was exactly it.  "parking" the thread fixed everything.